# w3m keeps auto-refreshing

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, w3m

When I run `w3m 'google.com/search?unicode+smiley'` the page does load correctly, but it keeps refreshing every 0 seconds until I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

I don't think I changed any of my `w3m` settings and this is a new behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

w3m has been known to have problems with `http-equiv="refresh"`, which the google results page uses — the copy I see has no timeout.

Here are a few (not recent) reports mentioning w3m:

- [BUG: Search result HTML includes META REFRESH, causes looping until banned](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/hpzglVb9B5M)
- [Debian Bug report logs - #575032 meta refresh URL=?.. loops](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=575032)
- [Disable / override meta-refresh?](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2003/10/msg00974.html)

Comment: Thanks to the discussion in your first link (towards the bottom) I was able to edit `~/.w3m/config` which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `~/.w3m/config`. There is a line that says `meta_refresh 1`; change the `1` to a `0`.

---

More discussion in this link which @Thomas Dickey posted: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/hpzglVb9B5M. (Skip the first 4 or 5 to get to where they're attempting to answer it.)